# How do I declare multiple vars in JavaScript's "for" statement?

Tags: javascript

```
for(var i = 0, var p = ''; i < 5; i++)
{
    p += i;
}
```

Based on a JavaScript book i'm reading, this is valid code. When I test it doesn't work, and in FireBug I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: missing variable name
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var i = 0, var p = '';
```

should be

```
var i = 0, p = '';
```

the `var` keyword applies to the whole line.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like a typo.

You need to remove the second `var` and it will work perfectly:

```
for(var i = 0, p = ''; i < 5; i++)
{
    p += i;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var p = 0;
var i = 0;


for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    p += i;
}
```

or

```
for(var i = 0, p = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    p += i;
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason that `i` is set to `0` twice in the first example?

Answer (score 2):

remove the `var` from before `p = ''`.

Answer (score 2):

Don't repeat the [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/var), you only need it once in the declaration:

```
for (var i = 0, p = ''; i < 5; i++)
{
    p += i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't declare a variable in the second position termitation expression is
the following works

```
var p;
for(var i = 0, p = ''; i < 5; i++)
{
    p += i;
}
```

Comment: Does this mean the accepted answer is incorrect when it is not using a separate `var` for `p`?